# RabbitMQ security in mobile app

Tags: security, ssl, rabbitmq

I am using Rabbit MQ broker in one of mobile apps that we are developing, I am bit puzzled about security aspects. we are using cloud hosted rabbitmq and hosting platform has given us user name and password (which have been changed since) and we are using SSLconnection so not so much worried about MIM or eavesdropping.

my concern is anybody who knows host and port can make connection to rabbitmq, since we have mobile app we are storing rabbitmq user name and password on device (although encrypted) so I guess that anybody who gets physical access to device and somehow decrypts username password can login to rabbitmq, and once you are logged in you can pretty much do anything on rabbitmq like deleting queues etc..
How are MQ like Rabbitmq used in mobile environment. Is there a better / more secure way of using rabbitmq.

Comment: Can you create separate user(s) with custom rights (or just readonly access without any admin privileges)?

Comment: yes that's possible but even then the mobile app user needs some privileges like publishing etc. I don't want unauthorized user to connect from outside of my app and start publishing.

Comment: How does this problem resolved in other cases, e.g. in solutions without RabbitMQ or any other MQ in between?

Comment: Say if I have my custom client sever written using TCP sockets, even if you some how connect to sever you won't be able to do anything because you don't know the protocol, for mq protocol is open and hence anybody can connect and run commands as long as they are able to get username/password

Comment: If someone crack your app he can easily inspect TCP traffic and hence  operate in any way. Security through obscurity was proven as ineffective and dangerous.

Comment: If you are talking about sniffing traffic, ssl will at least make sniffing and reverse engineering very difficult

Comment: But any naive hacker can write 10 lines of code to get into rabbitmq

Comment: I mean is someone decompile your app he can establish even SSL connection and investigate any custom protocol on top of it. SSL is just MiM protection. To secure executable there are other techniques (more or less effective). And at this point question has no relation to RabbitMQ secure model.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, it is best to not have your mobile app connect to rabbitmq directly. Use a web server in between the app and RabbitMQ. Have your mobile app connect to your web server via HTTP based API calls. The web server will connect to RabbitMQ, and you won't have to worry about the mobile app having the connection information in it.

There are several advantages of this, on top of the security problem:

- better management of RabbitMQ connections
- easier to scale number of mobile users
- ability to add more logic and processing to the back-end, as needed, without changing the mobile app

creating a connection to RabbitMQ is an expensive operation. It requires a TCP/IP connection. once that connection is open it stays open until you close it. if you open a connection from your mobile app and leave it open, you are reducing the number of available connections to RabbitMQ. if you open and close the connection quickly, you are inducing a lot of extra cost in creating and closing the connections constantly.

with a web server in the middle, you can open a single connection and have it manage multiple mobile devices. the web server will handle the http requests and use the one connection to rabbitmq to push messages to it.

since an HTTP web request is a short-lived connection, you'll be able to handle more users in a short period of time, than you would with direct rabbitmq connections.

this ultimately leads to better scalability as you can add another web server to handle thousands more mobile app instances, while only adding 1 new RabbitMQ connection.

this also lets you add middle-tier logic inside of the web server. you can add additional layers of processing as needed, without changing the mobile app. change the web server code and redeploy as needed.

if you must do this without a server in the middle, you likely won't be able to get around the security issue that you're having. the mobile device will contain the necessary information to make the connection.

Comment: I am not sure if putting a web server in middle solves this problem. Also Http has same problems as you describe, like for Http you have to make a TCP connection as well, its not any lighter than making connection to rabbitmq. In fact http is much more intensive as compared to MQTT connection to rabbitmq.

Comment: an HTTP/HTTPS connection is "lighter" on rabbitmq. you can handle more traffic via web app than rmq, most of the time, as connections are not left open. MQTT does solve that problem for RMQ, but i still maintain the other benefits of web server make it worth having the middle layer.

Comment: regarding the security of the mobile app using the api: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/219028/how-to-safeguard-a-rest-api-for-only-trusted-mobile-applications - you could require the mobile app user to login, which would at least provide some level of authorization for the app as well.  but ultimately, i don't think you can get around the problem of "fake" clients.