# Should RabbitMQ messages be queued directly from a front end application, or go through a backend endpoint first?

Tags: node.js, react-native, rabbitmq

Is it best to make API calls directly to RabbitMQ from the frontend React Native app, or is it better to make an API call to a backend server endpoint, and bind/queue the messages there, in order to return a JSON response to the frontend once the message is consumed?

My plan is to make a React Native app that uploads large files to Digital Ocean Spaces, and then store other data in Firebase collections. I have a Node.JS Express server running on the backend, and I'm wondering if it's best to queue RabbitMQ messages by going through the Express server first, or if I should just queue the messages to RabbitMQ directly from the frontend React Native app?

[Here's a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601914/rabbitmq-react-native-send-example/49818375) of an example `fetch()` API call to RabbitMQ directly from a frontend React Native app, but I'm wondering how secure this is (because you need to pass user and password credentials in a JSON object), and if it's best to just send all messages to the backend Express server first. I suppose a lot of this may depend on app architecture, but my thinking is that it's best to queue, produce, and consume messages by first going through a 3rd-party client library on the backend, using [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) for example, especially since most RabbitMQ examples found online do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RabbitMQ security in mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433384/rabbitmq-security-in-mobile-app)